# Facebook native preload ad

Tags: java, android, kotlin, facebook

I'm an Android developer and currently, I'm trying to develop a Facebook ad in my existing code now I want to develop like **preload ad**, and after some screens, I need to show it without asking for a request or loading an ad.

If I have a preloaded **Facebook native ad** then need to display a direct preloaded native ad if we don't have a preloaded ad then we will try to load a new Facebook native ad.

How can I solve this issue?

---

I tried with a local variable that I have declared **NativeAdLayout** and tried to store a layout in this one variable when the listener gives an ad loaded then I'm doing store a layout but still not working.